# Displaying content when the barbutton is pressed - Logic Issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have to set an image to a `barButton`, and it works correctly.

If a `persons` age is greater than 20, i need to add image `A.png` to the barbutton, and if the persons age is less than 20 i will be adding B.png. This is a simple `if-else` statement

```
if (person >20)
// barbutton with A.png
else
// barButton with B.png
```

The action or when the user clicks on this button, the `buttonPressed` Method gets called. Now in this button press method i need to know which button was clicked. Was it the barbutton with `A.png` to `B.png`.

How can i do this ?

```
- (void)buttonPressed : (id)sender {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `button.tag = someInteger;`.

```
- (void)buttonPressed : (id)sender 
{
UIBarButton *button = (UIBarButton *) sender;
if(button.tag == someInteger)
{
//YOUR CODE
}
}
```

Comment: Is there any other way to do this, without using tags ?

Comment: Furthermore, i can't use tags, because i only have one button, and i will be adding 2 different images when the user is greater than or less than 20. Is there a way i could get which image the BarButton has ? or any other approach ?

Comment: make a BOOL and keep its value different when setting image A or B..then check which bool is there..

Answer (score 0):

You could use tags on one button. like so:

> if (person>20){
>        button.tag =1;
>       button.image = imageA; 
>   }
>
> else{
>        button.tag =2;
>     button.image = imageB;
>   }

and you may know which button is clicked based on tag you set.

> -(void)buttonPressed : (id)sender {
>
> int tag = ((UIBarButton*)sender).tag;
>        if (tag ==1)
>         //button with imageA.
>      else
>        //button with imageB.
>   }

Comment: I am adding the Button to a BArButton. SO how will the buttonPressed method look like. You have used UIBUtton in it, but i whats i want is UIBarButton

Comment: it's the same. just change `UIButton` to `UIBarButton`. i've edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use tags, I assume you have the buttons set up as outlets in your header file like:

// In header

```
         @property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton* button1; 
         @property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton* button2;
```

// In implementation

```
         @synthesize button1;
         @synthesize button2;

         -(void)buttonPressed:(id)sender{
               if(sender==button1){
                   execute code for button1;
                }
               else 
                   execute code for button2;
         }
```